# PCA of stock returns

Tags: python, pca

I have a particular stock returns and want to find which of these returns can be used to explain the whole set of returns. Hence I am using PCA to the top 2 returns to explain the returns of a stock. I have taken the log return of the stock.

My code looks like this:

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
pca = PCA(n_components=2)
pcadata = stock['lr']
pca.fit(pcadata)
first_pc= pca.components_[0]
second_pc = pca.components_[1]
```

When i run this, I get this error:

```
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

How do i resolve this error?

Comment: Your data is clearly 1D. So why are you trying to use PCA? AFAIK PCA is only applicable when you want to reduce the number of features you have to reduce noise and the curse of dimensionality. Fitting a curve will be your best bet.

Comment: the data is 125 x 1

Comment: but it consists of 125 datapoints of 1D. Your each datapoint is a scalar. Your dataset is a vector.

Comment: so there is no way, i can find the best 2 returns to explain the whole set of returns?

Comment: What are your returns stand for? Sometimes a simple `max` function can do the trick. You have numerous robust options to use in the 1D space. From curve fitting to histogram and etc.

Answer (score 0):

PCA is a dimension-reduction procedure therefore you need a 2D array of samples x variables. PCA will then look for the combinations of variables that vary the most within these samples. It looks like you are only including one variable which is `stock['lr']`; therefore you receive the error. Perhaps you could give us a little more explanation about your data so that we could deduce how you should input your data.

Reading your comments (I can't reply because I need 50 reputations to do that...), I think you might have mistaken the use of PCA. You are looking for representative sample while PCA gives you 'representative' variables.